# Где можно найти скомпилированных LibGDX v.1.9.6?

Tags: libgdx

Где можно найти уже собранную libGDX последней версии, то есть .class файлы? Мне она нужна, так как единственная машина для разработки у меня сейчас - это телефон на android. Быть может, можно как-нибудь собрать исходники на телефоне, но пока у меня не получилось.

Answer (score 0):

[Репозиторий maven](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.badlogicgames.gdx/gdx) - там хранятся скомпилированные библиотеки.